# How do I cache an MVC3 ActionResult that returns Json?

Tags: json, outputcache, actionresult

I have a controller ActionResult that returns JSON that I would like to cache.  After doing some research, I have found that the OutputCache Attribute can do the trick, but haven't been able to successfully use it.  Here's the method call that I'm using it on:

```
    [OutputCache(Duration = 86400, VaryByParam = "none")]
    public ActionResult GetCategories()
    {
        var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(EXTERNAL API CALL);
        request.Accept = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
        var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        string result;
        using (var sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            result = sr.ReadToEnd();
        }
        return Json(result);
    }
```

This method makes an API call to an outside source, reads the result and then returns the result as a json to an AJAX call.  With the OutputCacheAttribute in place, the ajax call returns a 500 (Internal Server Error).  Without this attribute, it works just fine.

Am I doing anything wrong, or is there a better suggestion that I should use for this situation?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case someone has a similar issue, I figured out the problem.  I had CacheProfile set to a value that didn't exist in the web.config.  I know I didn't have that attribute set in my question, so... sorry if there was any confusion.

Comment: That's OK, +1.  I had *exactly* this problem with a controller method that returned an image.  The CachProfile was the default value, and the cache control wasn't used in web.config.  You pointed me the right way.